# Yup validate child of an object against a child of another object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, yup

I have two objects: sending country and receiving country. Each of these two objects have other fields but I'd like to validate only one of them. I'd like to check whether the receiving country is the same as the receiving country, and if it is, return an error. I tried the following schema but it doesn't work. Do I miss something?

```
const validationSchema = object({
    sending_country: object({
        name: string().ensure().required().max(100, "Name too long")
    }),
    receiving_country: object({
        name: string().ensure().required().max(100, "Name too long").when(
            "$sending_country.name", (sending_country, schema) => {
                return schema.test({
                    test: receiving_country => receiving_country.name !== sending_country.name,
                    message: "Both countries cannot be identical"
                })
            })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up mixing solutions a bit

```
const validationSchema = object({
    sending_country: object({
        name: string().ensure().required().max(100, "Name too long")
    }),
    receiving_country: object().shape({
        name: string().ensure().required().max(100, "Name too long")
    }).when(
        "sending_country", (sending_country, schema) => {
            return schema.test({
                test: receiving_country => receiving_country.name !== sending_country.name,
                message: "Both countries cannot be identical"
            })
        })

})
```